# How does the iptables work with IPv6?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ipv6

I would like to set up a firewall on Linux Debian for IPv6. It is important to use iptables for me. I have tried to change the ipv4 folder to ipv6.

[image]

How can I set up iptables for IPv6?

Comment: What's the problem with just replacing iptables with ip6tables?

Comment: Just one thing: I don't know how can do it?

Comment: Did you read ip6tables man page?

Comment: @blackcornail: btw, **it would be highly beneficial** for anyone searching the web **if you replaced your screenshot** by an actual preformatted paragraph with the script contents.

Comment: @blackcornail Not sure if you or anyone else noticed. You've a syntax error there in your `start)` section.  `iptables -nat -A ...` should be  `iptables -t nat -A ...`

Comment: dowvoted question for including a screenshot instead of searchable text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the existing answer.

If you prefer (like I do) to use the syntax from the `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` command `ip6tables-save` and `ip6tables-restore` can be used.

The convenient part is that you can *share* the same rule file for `iptables-restore` and `ip6tables-restore` respectively by prefixing all the version-specific lines with `-4` and `-6` respectively and leaving it out on lines that apply to both IPv4 *and* IPv6.

In order to to check for the correct address family (`$ADDRFAM`) in your script, use:

```
set -e
case "$1" in
start)
  case $ADDRFAM in
  inet)  iptables-restore  < /etc/myfwrules.txt ;;
  inet6) ip6tables-restore < /etc/myfwrules.txt ;;
  esac
  # ...
  ;;
stop)
  # ...
  ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the command `ip6tables` instead of `iptables`. In most (all?) ways that matter, it works the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ip6tables` instead of `iptables` And the following command is available:

`ip6tables-restore` and `ip6tables-save`